# If string ends with these characters, then

Tags: php

I have the following string examples:

```
$text = 'Hello world. '; // true
$text = 'Hello world? '; // true
$text = 'Hello world! '; // true
$text = 'Hello world.   '; // true
$text = 'Hello world.'; // true

$text = 'Hello world '; // false
$text = 'Hello world'; // false
$text = 'Hello world-'; // false
```

If string ends with `.` or `?` or `!`, then return true, otherwise, return false.

What's the best approach to this?

Comment: Are you asking how you can check what the last character in the string is?

Comment: I see your string that end with space return true, but it contradicts your expectation. can you clarify that ??

Comment: `return strlen(rtrim($text)) != strlen(rtrim($text, '.!? '));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr`, `rtrim` and `strpos` for this, like this:

```
$result = strpos("!?.", substr(rtrim($text), -1)) !== false;
```

This will set `$result` to *true* or *false* as you have indicated.

Comment: This is my choice of approach!

Comment: Glad you appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're asking how you can test what the last character of the string is, you can use `substr()`.

You can write an `if` statement like this:

```
<?php
// Test if the last character in the string is '!'.
if (substr($text, -1) === '!') {
    return true;
}
```

If you want to remove the blank spaces at the end of the string, you can use `$text = trim($text)` first.

If you want to test all the examples, you can use `in_array()` with an array containing all the characters you want to test.

```
if (in_array(substr(trim($text), -1), array('!', '.', '?', )) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: While this checks the very last character against "!", it doesn't work with all the examples I listed above. Please see the string variable examples for clarification on which that should return true and which that should return false.

Comment: You can use `trim()` for this.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
if(preg_match('/[.?!]\h*$/', $string)){
      echo 'true';
} else {
     echo 'false';
}
```

This is a character class, `[]`, allowing one of the characters inside. The `$` is the end of the string. The `\h*` is any amount of horizontal whitespace after the symbol and before the end of the string. If you want new lines as well to be allowed use `\s*`.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yS3fQ6/1

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/495500

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match to find those special string endings.

```
$text = array();
$text[] = 'Hello world. '; // true
$text[] = 'Hello world? '; // true
$text[] = 'Hello world! '; // true
$text[] = 'Hello world.   '; // true
$text[] = 'Hello world.'; // true

$text[] = 'Hello world '; // false
$text[] = 'Hello world'; // false
$text[] = 'Hello world-'; // false

foreach($text as $t) {
  echo "'" . $t . "' " . (hasSpecialEnding($t) ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
}

function hasSpecialEnding($text) {
  return preg_match('/(\?|\.|!)[ ]*$/',$text);
}
```

Output:

```
'Hello world. ' true
'Hello world? ' true
'Hello world! ' true
'Hello world.   ' true
'Hello world.' true
'Hello world ' false
'Hello world' false
'Hello world-' false
```

You can see the code in action here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51d839a523b940b4b4d9440cc7011e3f2f635852