# php regex: if line doesn't end with... remove line

Tags: php, regex

I have a string stored in variable `$text`:

```
$text = '
I should not be removed. 
I should not be removed.
I should not be removed?
I should not be removed! 
I should be removed
I should be removed-
I should not be removed?     
';
```

I want to remove all lines in the string that do not end with `.`, `?` or `!`. How do I do this effectively? Maybe a `preg_replace()` approach?

Comment: I will bounty this question with 50 points once it's eligible.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Splitting the string into lines and then removing lines in a loop would be perfectly respectable... and not to mention a lot easier to read.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [*If string ends with these characters, then*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534368/if-string-ends-with-these-characters-then). There, each line is tested as separate strings, here, a multiline string should be processed in one go.

Comment: @stribizhev I find the multiline requirement hardly justifiable to not mark this a dupe. It's trivial to adapt the solutions given in that other question to a multiline string or to handle the individual lines in that multiline string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If there is no whitespace at the end of the lines**, you can use

```
'~^.*(?<![.?!])$\R?~m'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC9tW2/3)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of line (as `/m` modifier indicates the multiline mode when `^` and `$` match start and end of *line*, not string)
- `.*` - any characters but a newline up to...
- `(?<![.?!])$` - the end of the string that is not preceded with a `.` or `!` or `?`
- `\R?` - optional line break

**To ignore the trailing whitespace**, use a lookahead based regex:

```
'~^(?!.*[.?!]\h*$).*$\R?~m'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC9tW2/4)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!.*[.?!]\h*$)` - a negative lookahead that fails a match if there is a `.`, `?` or `!` at the end of the string followed by optional horizontal whitespace (`\h*`)
- `.*$` - any characters but a newline, 0 or more occurrences, up to the end of the line
- `\R?` - optional newline sequence (optional, as the last line may not be followed with a newline character).

[PHP code demo](http://ideone.com/kcEpGN):

```
$re = '~^(?!.*[.?!]\h*$).*$\R?~m'; 
$str = "I should not be removed. \nI should not be removed.\nI should not be removed?\nI should not be removed! \nI should be removed\nI should be removed-\nI should not be removed?     "; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
echo $result;
```

**If you need to ignore the whitespace *and punctuation***, just add a `[\p{P}\h]` character class to the lookahead:

```
^(?!.*[.?!][\p{P}\h]*$).*$\R?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC9tW2/7). Now, the lookahead looks like `(?!.*[.?!][\p{P}\h]*$)`. It fails a match if there is a `.`, `?`, or `!` followed by punctuation (`\p{P}`) or horizontal whitespace (`\h`), zero or more occurrences (`*`).

**AND FINAL UPDATE: If you need to also ignore all non-word symbols (including Unicode letters) and all HTML entities**, you can use

```
'~^(?!.*[.?!](&\w+;|\W)*$).*$\R?~m'
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH8aS5/9) and an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/MvZAWk). The lines ending with `. &Acirc;&nbsp;` and `. Ã‚Â` do not get removed.

The difference here is `(&\w+;|\W)*` that matches 0 or more substrings starting with `&` and followed by 1 or more word characters (letters `[A-Za-z]`, digits (`[0-9]`) or an underscore) and then a semi-colon, or non-word characters (`\W`). *You can **unroll** the pattern* as [`[^\w&]*(?:&\w+;\W*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/gH8aS5/10) so that the regex performance might improve.

*Note* that you can use `\W` to match all Unicode letters and symbols other than ASCII since the `/u` modifier is not used here.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but that regex demo is removed lines that shouldn't be removed...? (probably because they have a white space at the end...)

Comment: Yes, the line ends with a space so it's removed, do you wish to ignore whitespace?

Comment: @Scuzzy Yes, ignore white space.

Comment: I added a second regex that uses a lookahead anchored at the start that does all the checking beforehand.

Comment: @stribizhev this is fantastic. For completion, can you please add a preg_replace() example of the second regex (ignoring whitespaces)?

Comment: While your example works, why doesn't it work with actual line separation: http://pastebin.com/HS9dGve1

Comment: I copied/pasted that code from pastebin to IDEONE and [unwanted lines get removed](http://ideone.com/MlXN92).

Comment: Try copy/paste that exact code to http://phptester.net/ and you will see the issue.

Comment: Just use `echo preg_replace($re, "", $str);`. This code works for me at that Web site: `$re = '~^(?!.*[.?!]\h*$).*$\R?~m'; 
$str = "I should not be removed. \nI should not be removed.\nI should not be removed?\nI should not be removed! \nI should be removed\nI should be removed-\nI should not be removed?     "; 
echo preg_replace($re, "", $str);`.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you for this ridiculously awesome solution. I have one final question if you don't mind. I have updated the regex page you linked: https://regex101.com/r/aC9tW2/6 --- is it possible to not remove the line if it ends with **.)** or similar? The text on the updated regex page explains my question better. I will definitely bounty this 50 points tomorrow when it's eligible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99423/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-henrik-petterson).

Comment: @stribizhev I have started the bounty and will leave it for a couple of days to provide some positive awareness, then I'll accept it :D

Comment: @stribizhev We ran this regex through 100 different type of text, and it failed in one way, multiple times. Please see how the $text ends in this example: http://ideone.com/NMFWc7 -- Is there anyway to add an exception for these types of instances (which are quite common in our tests)? It currently removes the line as you can see.

Comment: Could you please precise the new requirements? Ignore any HTML entities at the end of the string? Try [`^(?!.*[.?!](?:[\p{P}\h]|&\w+;)*$).*$\R?`](https://regex101.com/r/gH8aS5/1).

Comment: @stribizhev Ah, I see the problem in our local testing. I think some unicode character might be interfering with this regex. Here is a basic example: http://ideone.com/5rEHjT

Comment: It looks like you can use a much simpler [`'~^(?!.*[.?!]\W*$).*$\R?~m'`](http://ideone.com/W8ABXs) regex. Please check.

Comment: @stribizhev Very sorry to bug you about this continuously, but the regex is still incorrect. As you can see in this example, it doesn't remove any of the lines which should be removed: https://regex101.com/r/gH8aS5/3

Comment: If you test at regex101.com, do not forget to use `/g` global modifier. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH8aS5/4).

Comment: @stribizhev Ah, I suspect the error was on my end. This is still not working with lines containing unicode as I noted earlier, please see the example: https://regex101.com/r/gH8aS5/5 -- EDIT: the unicode approach you suggested earlier doesn't work with HTML entities: https://regex101.com/r/gH8aS5/6

Comment: So, just combine them: [`^(?!.*[.?!](&\w+;|\W)*$).*$\R?`](https://regex101.com/r/gH8aS5/8)

Comment: That is in every way exactly what I am looking for. Thank you **so much**!

Comment: If you will edit the answer, please add the new solution at the end of the answer and don't remove remove the previous solutions as they may come in handy for other users. I think this entire thread has worked as a type of tutorial! :D Thanks again.